# How to perform click after tap with x y co-ordinator in appium1.7.1 for ios

Tags: appium

In my application having x,y co-ordinators I am able to perform tap but I am not able to perform click on x,y co-ordinators. Please help me to click on below x y co-ordinators after tap

```
TouchAction touch1 = new TouchAction(driver);
touch1.tap (80, 300).perform();
```

Comment: Code formatted, improved spelling

Answer (score 0):

You can try `press` action to click by coordinates:

```
new TouchAction(driver)
    .press(x, y)
    .waitAction(500)
    .release()
    .perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

To Tap on particular element in appium is working for me no need to click again

Answer (score 0):

Below given code is working fine for me to tap and click,
We have to provide x,y possition

TouchAction touch3 = new TouchAction(driver);

touch3.tap (102,147).perform();

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to perform click after you are tapping the element which will not work as once you tap on the element it will redirect you to another screen and there will be no element to click again